# Aliasing structures (or pasting definition of one into another)

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I want to create an API for setting and getting fields of a structure in an opaque way (clients should only deal with pointers to them and pass them to the methods declared in the header files). Standard stuff, you define your structures inside the library's source files and do

```
typedef struct __internal_struct shiny_new_opaque_type;
```

Problem is that at the moment, the class is simply a wrapper around an already existing API (that will change soon). So the structures I need to use are defined in other header files (full structure declaration is there, the one I want to hide from my clients, so any attempt to dereference a pointer and access a structure member will result in a compiler error). Hence, I don't want to include those headers in my header (only in the .c files). I see three possible ways of dealing with it.

1. Instead of

   ```
   typedef struct __internal_struct shiny_new_opaque_type;
   ```

   do

   ```
   typedef void shiny_new_opaque_type;
   ```

   and have my methods do pointer casting. This is dangerous since the compiler can't do type checks.
2. Copy paste the structure definitions I'm currently using under a new `struct __internal_struct` (eventually I'll have to define my own struct anyway). Maybe this is the best option?
3. Define my `__internal_struct` for now to include a single member that is the corresponding structure from the other API I'm using and use that. Kind of ugly...

Basically is there a way to typedef one structure to another or use an already defined structure as an anonymous member inside another, so that at the end of the day both structures are equivalent? Neither of the following works:

```
typedef struct transparent_struct struct __internal_struct;
struct __internal_struct
{
      struct transparent; // anonymous, direct access to its members
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
From the comments, seems to me that 3, or a variation thereof, would be the way to go. There is also the possibility of never defining my struct, as @Akira pointed out. So

1. In header: `typedef struct my_type; // never defined`

And in my source always use it with a cast (struct transparent*)my_type_ptr

2. In header: `typedef struct _internal_struct my_type;`

And in source files:

```
struct _internal_struct {
    struct transparent t;
}
```

Then I can either one of those:

- `my_type_ptr->t.member`
- `((struct transparent*)my_type_ptr)->member`

Comment: No, it not possible\

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore and either another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for any use by 'the implementation' — you should not create such names in your own code.  Names starting with an underscore (and a digit or lower-case letter) are reserved for a more limited set of uses. See section §7.1.3 of the standard.  Avoid leading underscores; don't use leading double underscores.  Implementations use the convention because they're obliged to do so to keep out of your way.  Don't go getting in the way of the implementation.

Comment: Avoid option 1 — the API shouldn't use void pointers because of the lack of type safety.  C is bad enough as it is; don't go out of your way to drive holes through what type safety is available.  Option 2 is a maintenance liability, if not nightmare.  Option 3 is the way to go.  You have two options. 3A — your structure simply contains a single member that is a pointer to the API's structure type (`struct internal_struct { struct API *api; }`), and 3B — your structure simply contains a single member that is the API's structure type (`struct internal_struct { struct API api; }`).

Comment: Both 3A and 3B work; which works better for you depends on the organization of the API you're working with — how near to opaque it treats its structure type.  The more nearly opaque the structure type, the more appropriate 3A is.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler thanks for your on double underscores, didn't know it. Indeed I ended up going with option 3B. In this case both the internal_struct and the api one are of the same size, aligned and I can either access the api's members using internal_struct->api.member or ((struct API*)interna_struct)->member. What's your view on those two options? Would be helpful to many if you write it as an answer.

Comment: While the version with the cast works, it sucks as notation.  Avoid casts whenever you can — they're a bludgeon that tells the compiler "I know better than you do what I'm doing".  I don't trust myself to do that when I don't have to, but I've only been coding in C for somewhat over 30 years, so maybe I'm just a slow learner or something.  Other people happily bludgeon the compiler into submission, and sometimes don't run into problems for doing so.  Yes, I sometimes use casts; that's almost unavoidable.  But I avoid them when possible, and this is a case where it's eminently possible.

Comment: Using option 3B, the chances are the compiler generates the same code for both `internal_struct->api.member` and `((struct API *)internal_struct)->member`.  So, use the cleaner notation — which is also more succinct.  There's a mild nuisance from repeating the `api.`; there's a bigger nuisance from adding parentheses and repeating `struct API *`.  If you did the cast once: `struct API *api_ptr = (struct API *)internal_struct;` and then used `api_ptr->member` etc throughout, that might be sensible, but the castless `struct API *api_ptr = &internal_struct->api;` would still be better.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning to use [opaque pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C), you should provide only an **incomplete** `struct` type to users and let them do the operations through the provided functions where one the parameters is a pointer to your incomplete `struct` type.

For example, let's consider that we have an API which provides a `struct foo` type and a `void print(struct foo*)` function to print the content of `struct foo` instances. A wrapper can be implemented as follows:

**wrapper.h**

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

struct my_obj; /* incomplete type, but you can use pointers to it */

struct my_obj* create(void); /* creates new struct my_obj instance */
void destroy(struct my_obj*); /* deletes the pointed struct my_obj instance */

void set_name_and_id(struct my_obj*, const char*, unsigned);
void show(struct my_obj*);

#endif /* WRAPPER_H */
```

**wrapper.c**

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "api.h" /* API only included here */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TO_FOO(my_ptr) ((struct foo*)my_ptr)

struct my_obj* create(void) {
    return calloc(1, sizeof(struct foo)); /* allocates memory for 'struct foo' */
}

void destroy(struct my_obj* obj) {
    free(obj);
}

void set_name_and_id(struct my_obj* obj, const char* name, unsigned id) {
    strcpy(TO_FOO(obj)->bar, name);
    TO_FOO(obj)->baz = id;
}

void show(struct my_obj* obj) {
    print(TO_FOO(obj)); /* accepts only 'struct foo' pointers */
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uMdLJbBAMj3EMFsI)</kbd>

When users include the `wrapper.h` from the example above, they won't see the `api.h` and won't be able to dereference the pointer to `struct my_obj` because it's an incomplete type.

---

To respond to your comment:

> In this case both the `internal_struct` and the api one are of the same size, aligned and I can either access the api's members using `internal_struct->api.member` or `((struct API*)internal_struct)->member`. What's your view on those two options?

According to [N1570](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C) draft ([c11](/questions/tagged/c11)):

**6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**

> 15 (...) A pointer to a structure object, **suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), **and vice versa**. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

So, both of your approaches are good and safe, it's up to you which one you like. Using `internal_struct->api.member` is clear, I would use this version.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely point 3 I was considering. I guess it's the only sensible thing to do...

Comment: @AaylaSecura, made some edits to remove the definition of my `struct my_obj` with only one member. Now it's closer to your 1st point, but instead of `void*` type it uses an incomplete type.

Comment: I like the answer, but I'm not particularly fond of wrapping casts in macros. You can get rid of the `TO_FOO` macro completely from `wrapper.c` in favor of a simple `typedef` in `wrapper.h` (e.g. `typedef struct my_obj my_obj;` You can then replace all `TO_FOO` with a simple `my_obj*` which also allows you replace `struct my_obj*` with simply `my_obj*`. Either way works, I guess it just depends on whether you like macros or typedefs...

Comment: @Akira, oh I see. I don't define my struct at all and simply use pointer casting. Good idea. This is also possible if I define it to include a single member (not a pointer) of the external API's, see my comment my original post. Not sure which approach is better, if any.

Comment: @AaylaSecura, updated my answer with response to your question in comments.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

Avoid option 1 — the API shouldn't use void pointers because of the lack of type safety. C is bad enough as it is; don't go out of your way to drive holes through what type safety is available.  If the interface type is `struct SomeThing *`, you can pass a `void *` to the function without wittering from the C compiler, but you can't pass a `struct SomeThingElse *` to the function (without a cast, but needing to add a cast should raise warning flags in your mind).  If the API uses `void *`, you can pass any pointer type to the function without any casts or warnings; that's highly undesirable.

Option 2 is a maintenance liability, if not nightmare.  Don't go there.

Therefore, option 3 is the way to go. You have two sub-options.

- 3A — your structure simply contains a single member that is a pointer to the API's structure type (`struct internal_struct { struct API *api; }`), and
- 3B — your structure simply contains a single member that is the API's structure type (`struct internal_struct { struct API api; }`) — the difference is the presence or absence of the `*`.

Both 3A and 3B work; which works better for you depends on the organization of the API you're working with — how near to opaque it treats its structure type. The more nearly opaque the structure type, the more appropriate 3A is.  On the other hand, it incurs some overhead in accessing the data.

> Indeed I ended up going with option 3B. In this case both the `internal_struct` and the api one are of the same size, aligned and I can either access the api's members using `internal_struct->api.member` or `((struct API*)interna_struct)->member`. What's your view on those two options?

While the version with the cast works, it sucks as notation. Avoid casts whenever you can — they're a bludgeon that tells the compiler "I know better than you do what I'm doing". I avoid casts as much as possible. Yes, I sometimes use casts; that's almost unavoidable. But I avoid them when possible, and this is a case where it's eminently possible.

Using option 3B, the chances are the compiler generates the same code for both `internal_struct->api.member` and `((struct API *)internal_struct)->member`. So, use the cleaner notation — which is also more succinct. There's a mild nuisance from repeating the `api.`; there's a bigger nuisance from adding parentheses and repeating `struct API *`.

If you did the cast once:

```
struct API *api_ptr = (struct API *)internal_struct;
```

and then used `api_ptr->member` etc throughout, that might be sensible, but the castless version would still be better.

```
struct API *api_ptr = &internal_struct->api;
```